# I can't permanently delete or download files

Tags: sd-card, photos, downloading, files, motorola-moto-e4

Whenever I try to permanently delete a photo in my photo gallery, I get a message saying "Can't delete from device." I've tried deleting files by plugging my phone up to my computer, but the files keep coming back sometime later after they're deleted. Not only that, but I'm also unable to download images or apps. Whenever I try to download an image or app it says "Download Pending" even though I have 114 MB of space free. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: 114MB free is not much. Also it can be free space on the wrong partition. Use an app like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) to check the free space on your partitions.

Comment: if you can not install apps, try if you can enable usb-debugging. from adb shell check the output of `mount` data and sdcard is rw. if it is ro (read-only) you probably have serious problems with emmc

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue. When I delete photos from the gallery I get a message saying it deleted but when I check the gallery again those are still there. And also When I get new photos those are not saving in the gallery.it's a Samsung J1. finally, I did a factory reset and the problem was solved.